# External SVG Color not changing even when using currentColor property in CSS file

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I am trying to change the color of an external SVG using a scss file. I have set the "fill" property of my external SVG to "currentColor", and defined the color for that specific ID, but the color is still not changing. I need to use currentColor because the color will depend on a variable, which will change based on a user configuration. The SVG also cannot be inline, and must remain external.

SVG

```
<svg id="mySvg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="<my design>"/>
</svg>
```

SCSS

```
#mySvg {
  color: blue; /* just a sample color, this is a variable in my CSS */
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to make it clearer how you are using the svg.

Comment: External SVG files are separate documents and CSS only applies per document.

Comment: You can keep files external, and inline them. Take inspiration from [my ``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Comment: Try using this codepen to generate a CSS filter that can change the color of SVG files: https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp